# How to make the table left-align with the header

Tags: html, alignment

I made a page containing a header and a table here http://www.datanumen.com/outlook-repair/compare.htm
Now, I want the left border of the table align with the left border of the header image. How to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following CSS code:

```
table {
   margin:auto;
   width: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: I try to insert inline CSS as follows:

style="margin:auto" for the table but it does not work. Thanks

Comment: The modified version is at http://www.datanumen.com/access-repair/compare_fixed.htm

Comment: Now there is a white block in the right part of the table and the table is still not left-aligned. See http://www.datanumen.com/access-repair/compare_fixed.htm